# Add Text & image on single html5 canvas alongwith dragging & rotation options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have seen few websites(like vistaprint.com) which allows users to create business cards. The designs are customized by users. Most of the sites use HTML5 canvas and displays text and images on it. There is only single canvas on which Name, email, address and logo/image and many more are displayed. All these fields/data can be rotated and zoom in/out depends on the requirement of the user and all these fields are dynamic.

My question is how can we display all these data on single canvas. I have tried using fillText. But for rotation & zoom I am unable to get into right approach. Also all the data must be draggable by user.

Please provide assistance for rotation & text/image zoom.

Thanks